# Why pipe get messy code when use valgrind --xml-fd

Tags: c++, encoding, valgrind

here is my code:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
fd[0];
fd[1];
std::string cmd = "valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --xml=yes --xml-fd=";
cmd += std::to_string(fd[1]);
cmd += " /tmp/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds_global/c/valgrind/ex/ex2";
system(cmd.c_str());
close(fd[1]);
int n = 1024;
char buffer[1024];
std::string r;
while (read(fd[0], buffer, n) != 0) {
    r += buffer;
}
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

the executable "ex2" code is:

```
    int *is;
    is[2] = 2;
    return (0);
```

here is [output](https://gist.github.com/782aad94fe4240088e6b), I get messy code like `<\360\034@`

**update**

when i use --xml-file, it output normal text like [this](https://gist.github.com/da213aea0f0816846eda)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, it's because `int n = 1024` istoo slow, following code will work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    fd[0];
    fd[1];
    std::string cmd = "valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --xml=yes --xml-fd=";
    cmd += std::to_string(fd[1]);
    cmd += " /tmp/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds_global/c/valgrind/ex/ex2";
    system(cmd.c_str());
    close(fd[1]);
    int n = 4096;
    char buffer[n];

    std::string r;
    while (read(fd[0], buffer, n) != 0) {
        r += buffer;
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

**but** I don't know why it's 4096? why it's not 2048, 1024, how to determine this value? if someone know, please change this answer